# Does golang have a local date concept?

Tags: go

Does golang's time package (or any other library) support the concept of a local date?
By local date, I'm referring to the concept supported by [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html), which is a date without a time or timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you refer to uses UTC :

> This chronology will be set internally to be in the UTC time zone for all calculations.

You can simply [get the UTC time](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UTC) using the `time` package and do calculations on that.

Comment: Is this a satisfactory solution? My concern is that there is a risk of unintentionally interchanging times with a timezone and times without. Ideally, they would be different types so that the compiler would enforce correct conversion. This is the sense in which JodaTime has 'local' types.

Comment: Emil answered my question, so I marked it as accepted.  As to the current situation, I completely agree that it is not a good solution when you need to work with dates that aren't a single point in time.  Ideally there'd be a Date type that just represents year/month/day, and correlates with the SQL DATE type.